# Cannot import module with CrawlerProcess

Tags: import, module, scrapy

I am using a CrawlSpider with scrapy command line. Everything is fine:

> scrapy crawl --nolog newproductcrawler

Now I want to use CrawlerProcess, and the item module crashes when I import it.

> Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError
>
> No module named 'productsupervision'

Same thing, in the setting.py, I enable the pipeline with a similar module, and it is not loaded.

```
from productsupervision.responseitem import ResponseItem
```

startUp.py

```
 [...]
 process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())
 process.crawl(NewproductcrawlerSpider ,url = 'http://www.example.com',domain='www.example.com' )
 process.start()
```

NewproductcrawlerSpider.py

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from array import array
from productsupervision.responseitem import ResponseItem #EXCEPTION
class NewproductcrawlerSpider(CrawlSpider):
  name = 'newproductcrawler'
```

the folder structure is (cannot paste img anymore! ;o(( )

+productsupervision

++spiders

+++newproductcrawler.py (the crawler)

+++startUp.py

++middlewares.py

++pipelines.py

++responseitem.py

++settings.py

+scrapy.cfg

I looking for how the way to import correctly the iteml module with CrawlerProcess

Answer (score 1):

Ok, found: 
startUp.py MUST be at the project root level. Same folder than scrapy.cfg